# Issue subtracting in mapping objects

Tags: javascript, html, filter, mapping

I am getting an undefined number when console logging my subtraction.

I am mapping the term years of presidents if a president served from 2010-2014 I should have the result of 4.

I tried splitting the object and subtract index 0 and 1 and return the difference between the two.

```js
let president = {
  "id": 44,
  "president": 44,
  "nm": "Barack Obama",
  "pp": "Democrat",
  "tm": "2009-2017"
}

let presidentFullName = president.nm.split(" ");
presidentYears = president.tm.split(" ");

myPresidents = {
  id: president.id,
  number: president.president,
  firstName: presidentFullName[0],
  lastName: presidentFullName[1],
  party: president.pp,
  yearsInOffice: presidentYears[0-1]
}

console.log(myPresidents);
```

i'm currently getting an undefined under the console.log for the "yearsInOffice"

Comment: `presidentYears[0-1]` is `presidentYears[-1]`,  it is not going to reference the two indexes.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The years in `tm` are seperated by a `-` and not a space. You need to split at `-`

```
presidentYears = president.tm.split("-");
```

Then you need to subtract the 2 values from the array returned

```
yearsInOffice: presidentYears[1] - presidentYears[0]
```

`presidentYears[0-1]` is trying to get the `-1` index from `presidentYears` array and it's undefined